# Add File extension in Bulk

Tags: excel

I have about 8000 product name in one of my xls file. I want add file extension in it. Like Picture to Picture.jpg ! Can some one help me for do this task ? Thanks

Comment: you have all the names in a column and you want to add extn to it?

Comment: @AniMenon ! Yes I want as you tell :)

Comment: write an excel formula to add first column value with the extn you want.

Comment: @AniMenon I do not know which formula I need to write for it, so why I have posted question here.

Comment: Ok. Check the answer. You have to just use `CONCATENATE(text1,text2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the first column contains the file names, then in the second column click on the first cell and type `=CONCATENATE(A1,".jpg")` then press enter.
Now just drag that formula down to the end to get it on all rows.

Comment: Thanks ! This is the result I will looking for ! Thanks a lot :)